# Access SVG inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I use SVG inisde my xhtml file. I can not get access to the text with id="Wert".
What is wrong, I want to change the color form blue to red.

Untitled Page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnLoad() {
        setTimeout("timer()", 1000);
    }

    function timer() {
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101); // Zahlen von 0..100

        var svgdocument = document.svgid.getSVGDocument( 'svgid');
        svgtext = svgdocument.getElement.ById('Wert');
        svgtext.setattribute('style','fill:red');


        setTimeout("timer()", 1000);
    }
</script>
```

40

Answer (score 5):

- `function OnLoad()` should be `onload = function ()` (case sensitive!)
- You should use `setInterval` instead of repeatedly calling `setTimeout`
- You should pass it a function, not a string to be evaled
- The getElementById method doesn't have a "." in it
- The getElementById method only exists on the document object
- You can't get an element using `document.id_of_element` except in some versions of IE (use getElementById instead)
- `setAttribute` has a capital A in the middle of it
- You should probably be using the NS versions of a lot of those methods since you seem to be working with a mixed namespace document
- You shouldn't generate a random number if you aren't going to use it